# Can i change orientation screen of devices by service?

Tags: android

Can I change orientation screen of devices from service? I want to make app which change orientation of devices. Can I change orientation another app from my (service, widget, app)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by 'dives', however if you wish to force change an orientation you can do it from an activity, like this:

```
mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

This will force the activity into landscape. Change to PORTRAIT to force the opposite.
You cannot do this from a service though, without activity context, because it doesn't make any sense - a service has no display context, so usually won't need to display anything. Therefore orientation is redundant and not needed for it.

Comment: I want to make something like this:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation&hl=ru